# Istio(1.4.2) : Circuit Breaker Doesn't work in case of Http 500

Tags: istio

Circuit Breaker trips for Http errors 502, 503, and 504 but not in the case of Http 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I could found in this [github issue](https://github.com/istio/api/issues/909)

> Within a mesh, gateway errors will be more common (502/503/504) while most sensible external services will return a 503 to shed load.
>
> Secondly we just made the outlier detection generic to both tcp and http. The consecutive gateway error applies only to http and will make no sense in tcp context.
>
> I also feel that 500 error code is not something indicative of overload. The whole idea behind outliers is to remove overloaded servers from the lb pool.
>
> We don’t have very many users relying on this behavior I think. We kept it intentionally generic so that we can switch to a more specific error code in future (which happens to be now).

And there is [another one](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13612)

> See https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/destination-rule/#OutlierDetection
>
> Under consecutiveErrors: 502, 503, and 504s only, 500 codes will not trigger the outlier detection
>
> For HTTP services, hosts that continually return 5xx errors for API calls are ejected from the pool for a pre-defined period of time.
>
> So sounds like the docs are incorrect here. It will only work for 502/503/504

So based on the links provided above http 500 is not ready yet, but they're working on it and probably will be done soon.